# When the user clicks an option mark it with a tick or anything in html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a quiz website in php which shows questions from database with 4 options. Each questions is shown 1 at a time. I have my questions in questions table and answer marked as numbers in the same table using column answers. I have a back button for the user to move to the previous question and edit it. Below is my html with ajax:

```js
  <script>
  var currentQuestion = '';
  var preQuestion = 'false';
  function getPreQuestion(answer1=false, answer2=false, answer3=false, answer4=false){
      $.post("mohajax.php",
      {
          next_id: currentQuestion,
          answer1: answer1,
          answer2: answer2,
          answer3: answer3,
          answer4: answer4,
      },
      function(data, status){
          $('#container_for_questions').html(data);
      });
  }
  function getQuestion(curr_id, answer1=false, answer2=false, answer3=false, answer4=false){
      if(curr_id != -1){
        currentQuestion = curr_id; // Set the value of curret question in global variable
        preQuestion = 'true'; }// Set previous question to true // Set previous question to true
      $.post("mohajax.php",
      {
          next_id: parseInt(curr_id)+1,
          answer1: answer1,
          answer2: answer2,
          answer3: answer3,
          answer4: answer4,
      },
      function(data, status){
          $('#container_for_questions').html(data);
          if(preQuestion == 'true'){
            $('#container_for_questions').append("<button onclick='getPreQuestion()'>Previous<button>");
          }
      });
  }

  function getCorrectAnswer(curr_id, answer1=false, answer2=false, answer3=false, answer4=false){
      $.post("mohajax_get_correct_answer.php",
      {
          next_id: parseInt(curr_id),
          answer1: answer1,
          answer2: answer2,
          answer3: answer3,
          answer4: answer4,
      },
      function(data, status){
          $('#container_for_questions').html(data);
      });
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
          $('body').on('click','input[type="radio"]', function(){
              var curr_id = $('.question').data('nextQuestion');
              var answer1 = $('#radio1').is(':checked');
              var answer2 = $('#radio2').is(':checked');
              var answer3 = $('#radio3').is(':checked');
              var answer4 = $('#radio4').is(':checked');
              getCorrectAnswer(curr_id, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4);
            setTimeout(
                getQuestion.bind(this,curr_id, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4), 1000);

      });
      getQuestion(-1);
  });

  </script>
```

```html
<div class="services">
 <div class="zubi"><div class="container" id="container_for_questions"></div></div>
</div>
```

the questions are fetched using the following php file:

```html
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","quiz"); // change here to your data
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Check the number of all questions, if next_id is more than last question, back to first or whatever you want;
$response=mysqli_query($con,"select * from moh limit 25");
$number_of_all_questions = mysqli_num_rows($response);

if($_POST['next_id'] == 0){
 // reset to default
 $_SESSION["correct_score"] = 0;
 $_SESSION["not_correct_score"] = 0;
}


if($number_of_all_questions <= $_POST['next_id']){
 // Quiz finished, show results
    echo"<div>
 <h2>Results:</h2>
 <p>Correct answers: {$_SESSION['correct_score']}</p>
 <p>Wrong answers: {$_SESSION['not_correct_score']}</p>

 </div>";



}else{

 // query next question
 $response=mysqli_query($con,"select * from moh WHERE id =(select min(id) from moh where id > {$_POST['next_id']})");
 ?>

 <?php while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($response,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ ?>

  <div id="question_<?= $result['id'] ?>" class='question' data-next-question="<?= $_POST['next_id'] ?>"> <!--check the class for plurals if error occurs-->
   <h2><?= $result['id'].".".$result['question_name'] ?></h2>
   <div class='align'>
    <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1' name='1'>
    <label id='ans1' for='radio1'><?= $result['answer1'] ?></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio2' name='2'>
    <label id='ans2' for='radio2'><?= $result['answer2'] ?></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio3' name='3'>
    <label id='ans3' for='radio3'><?= $result['answer3'] ?></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio4' name='4'>
    <label id='ans4' for='radio4'><?= $result['answer4'] ?></label>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <?php /*<input type="button" data-next-question="<?= $_POST['next_id'] ?>" id='next' value='Next!' name='question' class='butt'/> */?>
  </div>
 <?php }?>
<?php }?>
<?php mysqli_close($con); ?>
```

and the correct answer is fetched using the following php file.

```html
<style>
.green{
  background-color:;
  margin:2px;
  padding:2px;
  color:black;
}
.red{
  background-color:;
  margin:2px;
  padding:2px;
  color:black;
}
</style>

<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","quiz"); // change here to your data
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// check correct unswer
if($_POST['next_id'] >= 0){
$correct_unswer=mysqli_query($con,"select answer from moh WHERE id =(select min(id) from moh where id > {$_POST['next_id']})");
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($correct_unswer,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$correct_answer = $result["answer"];

//get user answer
$user_answer = 1;
if($_POST['answer2'] != 'false') $user_answer = 2;
if($_POST['answer3'] != 'false') $user_answer = 3;
if($_POST['answer4'] != 'false') $user_answer = 4;

// Save results in session
if($correct_answer == $user_answer){
  $_SESSION["correct_score"] += 1;
}else{
  $_SESSION["not_correct_score"] += 1;
}



// query next question
$response=mysqli_query($con,"select * from moh WHERE id =(select min(id) from questions where id > {$_POST['next_id']})");
?>

<?php while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($response,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ ?>

<div id="question_<?= $result['id'] ?>" data-id="<?= $result['id'] ?>" class='question'> <!--check the class for plurals if error occurs-->
  <h2><?= $result['id'].".".$result['question_name'] ?></h2>
  <div class='align'>
    <?php $answer_class = ($correct_answer == 1)? 'green' : 'red' ; ?>
    <div class="<?=$answer_class?>"><?= $result['answer1'] ?></div>
    <?php $answer_class = ($correct_answer == 2)? 'green' : 'red' ; ?>
    <div class="<?=$answer_class?>"><?= $result['answer2'] ?></div>
    <?php $answer_class = ($correct_answer == 3)? 'green' : 'red' ; ?>
    <div class="<?=$answer_class?>"><?= $result['answer3'] ?></div>
    <?php $answer_class = ($correct_answer == 4)? 'green' : 'red' ; ?>
    <div class="<?=$answer_class?>"><?= $result['answer4'] ?></div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php }?>
<?php mysqli_close($con); }?>
```

I need to set a tick mark or something if the user clicks the back button, to show which option he visited previously. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could add a `$_SESSION['chosen']` variable and check on that when rendering the questions.

Comment: i dont know much coding. if u dnt mind can u explain as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already provide some input on the question like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50854971/5503275

Pass one flag with previous answer request

```
function getPreQuestion(answer1=false, answer2=false, answer3=false, answer4=false){
      $.post("mohajax.php",
      {
          'previous_question' : 'Yes', 
          next_id: currentQuestion,
          answer1: answer1,
          answer2: answer2,
          answer3: answer3,
          answer4: answer4,
      },
      function(data, status){
          $('#container_for_questions').html(data);
      });
  }
```

Add the value of last_answer in one session

```
$_SESSION["last_answer"] = $user_answer;
```

Add while creating radio option check with condition

```
<div class='align'>
    <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1' name='1' <?= (isset($_POST['previous_question']) && $_SESSION["last_answer"] == '1') ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>>
    <label id='ans1' for='radio1'><?= $result['answer1'] ?></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio2' name='2' <?= (isset($_POST['previous_question']) && $_SESSION["last_answer"] == '2') ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>>
    <label id='ans2' for='radio2'><?= $result['answer2'] ?></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio3' name='3' <?= (isset($_POST['previous_question']) && $_SESSION["last_answer"] == '3') ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>>
    <label id='ans3' for='radio3'><?= $result['answer3'] ?></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio4' name='4' <?= (isset($_POST['previous_question']) && $_SESSION["last_answer"] == '4') ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>>
    <label id='ans4' for='radio4'><?= $result['answer4'] ?></label>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah. i know. it was my friend's question

Comment: okey bro thanks. its working fine. can you clear my other doubt. you said use something like $totalQuestion = mysqli_query($con,"select count(answer) from moh");

Comment: what should i do after getting count

Comment: Your friend asks that the totally correct answer result goes up to total question, So I ask to get total question count, so you can then compare the total question and total answer

Comment: yes. the total answer has error. it shows the count of edited questions as well.

Comment: we are not good in coding. can you help me one last time. how can i solve this using your count

Comment: First, tell me that it might be your friend who is upvoting on my other answer, am I right?

Comment: yes i guess he is doing. i have used limit questions to limit data. so i have 25 questions in this file.

Comment: Please told him to stop doing this, If any question really help you then upvote this otherwise it won't make any sense, as it will be removed by stack on next day

Comment: please help me with this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173308/discussion-between-dsraj-and-zubair-nazer-oliyat).